Open link in new tab and keep back button history
I'd like to find a configuration or extension such that if I open a new tab either by right clicking and selecting 'Open Link in New Tab' or by clicking while holding Cmd then the new tab will also allow me to go back to the previous page, as if I hadn't opened the link in a new tab.
I am aware this can be done by first duplicating the tab and then clicking on the link. However, this has the following downsides:

I would need to be remember to do this everytime I choose to open a link in a new tab.
Duplicating the tab would can require computer resources, since it will have to make a new request.

I thought of writing a script that writes document.referrer values to the browser's history, but it would only give the previous page and not the whole history.

As far as I can tell, no prebuilt solution exists for what you want. The best current workaround is to duplicate the tab first like you mentioned.
However, it looks like someone has already suggested this feature for Firefox on their suggestions forum. It certainly wouldn't hurt to go give that post a thumbs up and/or a comment.
